# Quick ArrayList load

Tags: android, arraylist, expandablelistview

At the following code i am loading an ArrayList with data one by one.

This ArrayList is used in an ExpandableListView. So it contains groups and childs.

Every group has a Name and a Description.

Every child has a Name.

Some groups do not have childern.

```
public class CategoriesExpandableList extends Activity implements OnChildClickListener,
OnGroupClickListener, OnGroupExpandListener, OnGroupCollapseListener {

private static Context mContext;
private ExpandListAdapter ExpAdapter=null;
private ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> ExpListItems;
ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> list=null;
private ExpandableListView ExpandList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.categoriesexpandable);
    ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ExpList);   
    ExpListItems = SetStandardGroups();
    ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(CategoriesExpandableList.this, ExpListItems);
    ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);
    ExpandList.setOnGroupClickListener(this);
    ExpandList.setOnChildClickListener(this);
    mContext=this;
}

public ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> SetStandardGroups() {

            ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> list = new ArrayList<ExpandListGroup>();
            ArrayList<ExpandListChild> list2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();

            ExpandListGroup gru0 = new ExpandListGroup();
            gru0.setName("My Favorites");
            gru0.setDescription("My favourite points of interest");
            gru0.setItems(list2);
            list2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();

            ExpandListGroup gru1 = new ExpandListGroup();
            gru1.setName("Essentials");
            gru1.setDescription("Very essential points of interest");
            gru1.setItems(list2);
            list2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();

            ExpandListGroup gru2 = new ExpandListGroup();
            gru2.setName("Sights");
            gru2.setDescription("Beautiful sights you have to visit");
            gru2.setItems(list2);
            list2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();

            ExpandListGroup gru3 = new ExpandListGroup();
            gru3.setName("Beaches");
            gru3.setDescription("Beaches near Agios Nikolaos");
            ExpandListChild ch3_0 = new ExpandListChild();
            ch3_0.setName("In town");
            ch3_0.setTag(null);
            list2.add(ch3_0);
            ExpandListChild ch3_1 = new ExpandListChild();
            ch3_1.setName("Outside town");
            ch3_1.setTag(null);
            list2.add(ch3_1);
            gru3.setItems(list2);
            list2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();

            list.add(gru0);
            list.add(gru1);
            list.add(gru2);
            list.add(gru3);

            return list;
        }
```

}

I want to know if there is a quick way to load these data at the ArrayList. For example by calling a method like this:

```
addPoint(String groupname, String groupdescription, String child01)

addPoint("Banks", "Banks and ATMs", "Only banks")
addPoint("Banks", "Banks and ATMs", "Only ATMs")

// Here i have only a group and no children...
addPoint("Sights", "Beautiful sights to visit", "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> SetStandardGroups() {

            ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> list = new ArrayList<ExpandListGroup>();
            ArrayList<ExpandListChild> list2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();

            String[][] expandablelist={ {"My Favorites", "My favourite points of interest","","","","","","","","","",""},
                    {"Essentials", "Very essential points of interest","","","","","","","","","",""},
                    {"Sights", "Beautiful sights you have to visit","","","","","","","","","",""},
                    {"Beaches", "Nice beaches","In town","Around town","","","","","","","",""},
                    {"Banks", "Banks and ATMs","","","","","","","","","",""},
                    {"Pharmacies", "All pharmacies near you","","","","","","","","","",""},
                    {"Doctors", "Doctors in case of emergency","Pediatricians","Pathologists","General doctors","Eye doctors","Surgeons","Otorhinolayngologists","Orthopaedists","Gynecologists","Dermatologists","Cardiologists"}
            };

            for(int i=0; i<=6; i++) {

                System.out.println("i= "+i);      
                ExpandListGroup gru = new ExpandListGroup();
                gru.setName(expandablelist[i][0]);
                gru.setDescription(expandablelist[i][1]);


                for(int j=2; j<=11; j++) {
                    System.out.println("j= "+j);
                    System.out.println("length= "+expandablelist[i][j].length());
                    if(expandablelist[i][j].length()!=0) {
                        ExpandListChild chld = new ExpandListChild();
                        chld.setName(expandablelist[i][j]);
                        chld.setTag(null);
                        list2.add(chld);
                    }
                }
                if(list2!=null) {
                    gru.setItems(list2);
                }
                list2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();
                list.add(gru);
            }
}
```

I have founnd a way to load my ArrayList from an Array like you see at the code above.
Thank you for reading about my problem. 
I am sure there is a better solution and if i have some time i will try to figure it out.